# How to connect to Kubernetes service from local network?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm new in Kubernetes and I have problem with accessing to running service from another machine in my local network.
Running `minikube` on `Centos 9`
Below are my configurations:

1. mongo-express.yaml

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-express
          image: mongo-express
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-configmap
                  key: database_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30000
```

`$ minikube service mongo-express-service` command output:

```
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |         NAME          | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | mongo-express-service |        8081 | http://192.168.49.2:30000 |
|-----------|-----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
```

`$ kubectl get service` command output:

```
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes              ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          4d13h
mongo-express-service   NodePort    10.100.148.37    <none>        8081:30000/TCP   3s
mongodb-service         ClusterIP   10.105.122.101   <none>        27017/TCP        2m30s
```

My network interfaces:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:de:80:b8:24:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:de:80:b8:24:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.80/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2601:2c2:502:2f40:d188:581e:2837:cfe7/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 345587sec preferred_lft 345587sec
    inet6 fe80::8763:4506:5db7:afaa/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-a8f04f55d768: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:f1:0f:7d:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.49.1/24 brd 192.168.49.255 scope global br-a8f04f55d768
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:f1ff:fe0f:7dcb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The local ip for minikube host is `192.168.0.80`. On host I'm able to ping service `192.168.49.2`, but I'm able to ping and access it from any other machine in my local network.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access to the app you need to use node address and node port, double check your service details and firewall rules:

```
http://<public-node-ip>:<node-port>
```

Proceed with the following steps:

1. Display service information and notice the NodePort value

kubectl describe services mongo-express-service

2. List the pods running Mongo application

kubectl get pods --selector="YOURSERVICESELECTORMATCHLABEL" --output=wide

3. Get public IP of one of your nodes running a Mongo pod.

kubectl cluster-info

4. On your chosen node, create a firewall rule that allows TCP traffic
   on your node port. For example, if your Service has a NodePort value of 31568, create a firewall rule that allows TCP traffic on port
   31568
5. Finally access with the URL as stated at the beginning:

> ```
> curl http://<public-node-ip>:<node-port>
> ```

**Note: Cluster IPs differ than addresses in Network interfaces**

Comment: This steps still not fixed issue. I can access to service UI (http://192.168.49.2:30000) from host (192.168.0.80) but cannot from any other machine in my local network. The firewall rule for port 30000 added.